# How can you tell if a directory is writeable in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, file-io

I want to use an open panel to let the user select a destination, but I want to alert them at that point that point that the directory is not-writable. I generally prefer to create it and handle the error, but that's not useful to me here, since I don't want to create the folder just yet. (I'll be sure to handle the error when I do create it, if there is one.)

I thought there might be a better way than to just create it and delete it, which would stink.

I tried doing this, thinking that "file" might mean file or directory like some other methods.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
[fm isWritableFileAtPath:destinationString]
```

(I'm not sure yet if I want to offer the chance to authenticate to override permissions, but feel free to tell me how.)

Comment: I didn't think the panel would even allow you to select an inaccessible destination, but now that I think about it, I don't know if I've ever really tested that.

Comment: It can definitely let you choose something that's not writable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A directory's path ends with "/". Assuming your code is:

```
NSString* destinationString = [[panel URL] path];
[fm isWritableFileAtPath:destinationString];
```

You'll end up with a destinationString that does **not** end with "/", therefore `isWritableFileAtPath:` will be testing the possibility of writing to a file named "someDir" instead of the folder "someDir".

A quick fix would be to do this:

```
NSString* destinationString = [[panel URL] path];

if (![destinationString hasSuffix:@"/"])
    destinationString = [destinationString stringByAppendingString:@"/"];

[fm isWritableFileAtPath:destinationString];
```

Comment: @inkjet Thanks for figuring out why it was working some of the time.

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** Looks like inkjet figured out why I was getting inconsistent results. Marking his as the correct answer.

---

Weird. I tried isWriteableAtPath before and it didn't seem to work as I expected, but now with an isolated test does.

```
NSFileManager *fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSLog(@"%d /private/ writeable?", [fm isWritableFileAtPath:@"/private/"]);
NSLog(@"%d /Applications/ writeable?", [fm isWritableFileAtPath:@"/Applications/"]);
NSLog(@"%d /Users/MYUSERNAME/ writeable?", [fm isWritableFileAtPath:@"/Users/MYUSERNAME/"]);
```

Prints

```
0 /private/ writeable?
1 /Applications/ writeable?
1 /Users/MYUSERNAME/ writeable?
```

Answer (score 3):

You want

```
-attributesOfItemAtPath:error:.
```

-jcr

Comment: Does that mean I have to look at filePosixPermissions, fileGroupOwnerAccountName, fileOwnerAccountName, NSUserName, and figure it out for myself?

Comment: For a NSURL object you can check the NSURLIsWritableKey resource value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, directories count as files.

Comment: So, does that mean that if [fm isWriteableFileAtPath:@"/someDir/"] returns YES, I can create files in that directory?